# Python: importing file from another subdirectory

Tags: python, import

I have a directory structure like:

```
mycode
|
└-----dirA
|     └─---- fileA.py
└─----dirB
      └─---- fileB.py
```

How do I import `fileB.object` from `fileA.py`? I have `__init__.py`'s in all the folders, including "`mycode`", but I continually get errors that I can't find `fileB.py` from `fileA.py`, and relative imports don't work either.

Comment: To debug add `import sys print(sys.path)` to top of the file you are running.. This will give some idea about what are the folders currently in system path

Comment: Have you considered turning your code into a package and installing it in your environment?

Comment: How do you start the program and from which directory? Relative imports don't work with the top level script because its not part of a package.

Comment: This question can't be answered without knowing how `filaA.py` is executed. Are you in the `dirA` directory and running as a script (e.g. `python3 fileA.py`)? Does some other script `import mycode.dirA.fileA`? In either case, the parent of `mycode` needs to be in `sys.path`. The usual way to do that is to make the package installable, and then install it. There are tricks (hacks) to get around that, but installing is the normal solution.

Answer (score 1):

In python, there's a unique way of traversing the tree backwards:

- One period `.` for same directory
- Two periods `..` for parent directory
- Three periods for grand-parent...
- You get the point

Try using:

```
from ..dirB.fileB import <symbol>
```

Comment: This is the right answer, I didn't know about this part of the Python import system, +1. Anyway the Python's import system is a mess, unfortunately.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO - This is the right answer ... because you don't understand the import system? Ignore the upvotes. This won't work unless `mycode` is known as a package in python. The import system isn't a mess, its just that you have script executable paths and module paths (just like LIB paths in the operating system).

Comment: @tdelaney so you must sys.path.append the directory, right?

Comment: @tdelaney, if you want to import something that is not a direct descendant, this is a way to do it. There are additional ways, such as changing the PATH, which are not necessarily better or worse (it depends). You could argue that one should find a better way to structure their project tree, that's totally legitimate, but that's not the essence of the question IMHO.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO - You could insert or append. It just that the _parent directory_ of `mycode` has to be in `sys.path` somewhere. Python will scan all of the directories in sys.path for the package name. But that raises a second issue, `mypath` must already have been imported somewhere. The top level script, which is not in the package, or some other module needs to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sys.path.insert()` method:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './subdirectory')
import myfile
```

and you can read more about it [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-import-from-subdirectory/#:%7E:text=Import%20a%20File%20From%20the%20Subdirectory%20in%20Python,searches%20the%20sys.path%20to%20import%20the%20required%20module.)

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in an answer 2 minutes ago, but it got downvoted, so I guess the OP isn't searching for this kind of answer.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO there's a difference between ```sys.path.insert``` vs. ```sys.path.append```. Since Python will load the module that comes first and ignores the rest, then the OP's module in question would need to be inserted to ```sys.path``` at the first position (index 0 in this case), unlike ```append``` which adds the given path to the end of the ```sys.path```'s list, which is what they might be not looking for or didn't work for them.

Comment: @BlockDiagram01, sorry to disappoint you, but if there are no collisions, `append` and `insert` will do exactly the same. I don't think collisions were the essence of the question here, but rather one script being able to access the second one.

Comment: @BlockDiagram01 - I don't understand insert verses append. It has to be in `sys.path` - preferably by installing the module. Its position in the path doesn't make any difference unless you have multiple like-named packages. And that's a problem in itself.

Answer (score 0):

if the python outputted the result that you can't find the folders, you must set the directory properly like

it should be C:\Users\Desktop\DirectoryName

instead of FolderDirectory:FolderName

i mean you should set the proper path of the directory, since a program is not really that smart that can locate it easily, but just a bunch of instructions that you wanted to do it properly